# Is there a way to hyperlink bot responses sent through Dialogflow Messenger?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I am trying to have links hyperlinked in my bot's response text but I can't seem to get it to work, and I can't find any resources online about it. The messages would be sent through Dialogflow Messenger.

I tried markdown hyperlinks and html anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think response text use a hyperlink tag as a pure text.
The another way is to write tag in [accordion response](https://botflo.com/courses/dialogflow-messenger-how-to/lessons/how-to-generate-the-accordion-response-type/).